# How to avoid re-parsing Error when using enum that conforms to Error protocol in Swift

Tags: swift

There's an error enum:

```
@objc public enum MyError: Int, Error {
    case good
    case bad
    case ugly
}
```

Note that it's available to objective C - that's part of the challenge. For instance I cannot change enum to have associated values (like `case good(Error)`)

A decent solution is to have a constructor that can parse from some arbitrary error:

```
init(from error: Error?) {

     // parse it and set self to corresponding code, e.g.
     guard let error = error else { 
          self = .good
          return
     }

     if let uglyError = error as NSError? {
         self = .ugly
         return
     }

     self = .bad
}
```

But one of the cases this constructor has to handle is that provided error *is already* one of `MyError` values, i.e. `Error(MyError.ugly)` - this is simplification of course. More likely it's a result of lower-level error bubbling up.

In that case I want to avoid re-parsing it. How is that possible?

In pseudo-code I want to implement condition like this:

```
 if error is [one of MyError values] {
     self = error
     return
 }
```

Tried to do that with `CaseIterable` and `allCases`, but seems cannot convert `Error` to something that can be compared

```
    for value in MyError.allCases {
        if error == value { // <-- Error: Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Error' and 'MyError'

        }
    }
```

Any way to accomplish something like that? (I am not stuck on CaseIterable, anything else works too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are aiming to keep the same initializer as `init(from error: Error?)`, what you could do is to add

```
if let castedError = error as? MyError {
    self = castedError
    return
}
```

at the beginning (before doing anything).

As a full implementation, it should be similar to:

```
@objc public enum MyError: Int, Error, CaseIterable {
    case good
    case bad
    case ugly

    init(from error: Error?) {

        if let castedError = error as? MyError {
            print("Already MyError!")
            self = castedError
            return
        }

         guard let error = error else {
              self = .good
              return
         }

         if let _ = error as NSError? {
             self = .ugly
             return
         }

         self = .bad
    }
}
```

Therefore, the output would be:

```
let givenError: MyError = .good
let resultError = MyError(from: givenError)
print(resultError.rawValue) // 0 (which is .good raw value)
```

Note that it should also log "Already MyError!" because of the `print` statement in the first check to confirm that it has been reached.

It should also behave as expected with NSErrors:

```
let nsError = NSError(domain: "", code: 101, userInfo: nil)
let myError = MyError(from: nsError)
print(myError.rawValue) // 2 (which is .ugly raw value)
```